Tableau table with percent change in a mean value
Let me preface this by saying I'm very new to Tableau.  Most of my experience has been in R, and I wouldn't have any issues doing this is R and Shiny...but the user request is for Tableau so here goes.
I have many thousands of rows of data on the number of days it takes to process various types of cases.  The specifics aren't that important (and are proprietary anyway) but the general form of the relevant fiends is like



Area
Response Type
Start Date
End Date




A
Letter
12/15/2019
1/15/2020


B
Injunction
1/12/2021
5/6/2021


C
Investigation
2/2/2022
1/4/2023



I've been asked to generate three things (each with filters for Area and Response Type):

boxplots of all the processing times by fiscal year (FY)
line plots of the mean processing time by FY
a data table with the mean processing time for each FY and the percent change between the mean for 2018 and the mean for 2023

I have the first two done without issue.  I can extract the year and get it in the right FY, get the number of days between the two dates, and produce the plots.  The third one has me stumped though.  Particularly how to do the percent change calculation between the dynamically generated FY summary stats (the means).
Any pointers would be most appreciated!
